# Selecting a Cross Compiler

Tags: compilation, cross-platform, cross-compiling

After deciding the microcontroller (In my case it is STM32L1 series) what are the factors to be considered for selecting a cross compiler?

Comment: Do you mean the actual compiler or the development environment? Most commercial products for the STM32 are just wrappers around GCC and you pay for different debugger/IDE/libraries/support levels. The alternate compilers I know of are Keil (owned by ARM now) and IAR.

Comment: I meant the actual compiler. So from the perspective of your comment, I think only the debugging options, cost and support matters and no much technical differences may be there among various compilers. Am I right? An additional query from my part is if in case it was not STM32 what major differences can be there among various compilers (in a general perspective)

Comment: I think you still mean development environment - not the actual compiler itself (i.e. you're not concerned if the code generated is 1% more space efficient, or is certified for safety critical etc.). A question about which vendor's IDE/libraries etc is best will be very subjective. Why don't you just start downloading the demos and see which one you like the style of?

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the reply...I will try the option you suggested